# My localhost apache server isn't showing my index.html

Tags: apache, localhost

Recently, my localhost apache server stopped showing my index.html. It just shows "It works!" now. I'm not sure what to do. My httpd.conf file looks fine, but this is it:

http://pastebin.com/JQSEMUTy

and when I attempt to restart my apache server it gives:

httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Richard-Lus-MacBook-Pro.local for ServerName

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try http://mamp.info for mysql, php and apache. Btw, could you try delete line 230 and 232 and see if the server is picking up the index.html file

Answer (score 0):

I guess there was an update..?

```
DocumentRoot "/sites"
```

is this the document root you are using? If not, fix it. Also, set your servername:

```
ServerName www.example.com:80
```

Comment: Maybe you should add DocumentRoot is an absolute path, so it's usually something like /var/www/sites

Comment: Yes, I put my files into the /sites folder.

Sorry, but what exactly do I set for my ServerName? I usually access it by typing localhost/

And as of now, it is giving me the error `The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

Here is an updated file of my httpd.conf http://pastebin.com/eWCGFR0P

Thanks again!